# Kmeans clustering from a data file

Tags: java, bufferedreader, k-means, parseint

Ok so basically I have to do a kmeans clustering program where the data file is in the form

Also I'm sorry the code has lots of comments out, I was planning on cleaning it up after I got it to work

1    6.3    2.8    5.1    1.5

where 1 is the ID, followed by sepal length, sepal width, pedal length, and then pedal width. I'm getting an error relating to the input and how its being read into my doubly linked list. I use the first two entries to create the first two clusters which is why they are done separately, and the rest are read into whichever cluster they are closest to. I'm pretty sure the issue has to do with how I read in the file and then convert it to numerical values

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

(also I know it should be petal, I messed up)

```
public void read(String fname){
BufferedReader reader=null;
//listA=listA.linkedList();
//listB=listB.linkedList();
try{
FileReader fr=new FileReader(fname);
reader= new BufferedReader(fr);
Random rand=new Random();

int i;
//listA.DoublyLinkedList();
//listB.DoublyLinkedList();
for (i=0; i<2; i++){

String line=reader.readLine();
String values[]= new String[5];
values=line.split(" ");
int id=Integer.parseInt(values[0]);
double sepall=Double.parseDouble(values[1]);
double sepalw=Double.parseDouble(values[2]);
double petall= Double.parseDouble(values[3]);
double petalw= Double.parseDouble(values[4]);
//int j=rand.nextInt(2)+1;
if(i==0){
listA.insertAtEnd(id, sepall, sepalw, petall, petalw);
id1=id;
sepall1=sepall;
sepalw1=sepalw;
petall1=petall;
petalw1=petalw;
petal1=petall1*petalw1;
sepal1=sepall1*sepalw1;
}else{
listB.insertAtEnd(id,sepall,sepalw,petall,petalw);
id2=id;
sepall2=sepall;
sepalw2=sepalw;
petall2=petall;
petalw2=petalw;
petal2=petall2*petalw2;
sepal2=sepall2*sepalw2;
}
}
}catch(FileNotFoundException fne){
System.out.print("File not Found");
}catch(IOException ex){
ex.printStackTrace();
}finally{
//if(reader.readLine()==null){
    try{
reader.close();
}catch(IOException ex){
ex.printStackTrace();
}
//}
}
for(int i=2;i<150; i++){
try{
//String fname=args[0];
//BufferedReader reader= new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fname));
//Random rand=new Random();
FileReader fr=new FileReader(fname);
reader= new BufferedReader(fr);
//DoublyLinkedList listA= new DoublyLinkedList();
//DoublyLinkedList listB= new DoublyLinkedList();
//int i;
//listA.linkedList();
//listB.linkedList();
for (i=0; i<2; i++){

String line=reader.readLine();
String values[]= new String[5];
values=line.split(" ");
id= Integer.valueOf(values[0]);
sepall= Double.parseDouble(values[1]);
sepalw= Double.parseDouble(values[2]);
petall= Double.parseDouble(values[3]);
petalw= Double.parseDouble(values[4]);
//int j=rand.nextInt(2)+1;
petal=petalw*petall;
sepal=sepalw*sepall;
double s1=sepal1-sepal;
double s2=sepal2-sepal;
double p1=petal1-petal;
double p2=petal2-petal;
s1=Math.abs(s1);
s2=Math.abs(s2);
p1=Math.abs(p1);
p2=Math.abs(p2);

if(s1<s2){  //if sepal is closer to 2
    if(p1<p2){
        listB.insertAtEnd(id,sepall,sepalw,petall,petalw);
    }else{
        double s=s2-s1;
        double p=p1-p2;
        if(s>p){
            listA.insertAtEnd(id,sepall,sepalw,petall,petalw);
        }else{
            listB.insertAtEnd(id,sepall,sepalw,petall,petalw);
        }
    }
}else{
    if(p2<p1){
        listA.insertAtEnd(id,sepall,sepalw,petall,petalw);
    }else{
        double s=s1-s2;
        double p=p2-p1;
        if(s>p){
            listB.insertAtEnd(id,sepall,sepalw,petall,petalw);
        }else{
            listA.insertAtEnd(id,sepall,sepalw,petall,petalw);
        }
    }
}
}
}catch(FileNotFoundException fne){
System.out.print("File not Found");
}catch(IOException ex){
ex.printStackTrace();
}finally{
//if(reader.readLine()!=null){
    try{
        reader.close();
    }catch(IOException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
}
}
//}
}
}

public void itteration(){
int size=listA.getSize();
petal1=listA.calculateMeanPetal();
petal2=listB.calculateMeanPetal();
sepal1=listA.calculateMeanSepal();
sepal2=listB.calculateMeanSepal();
Node node=listA.getEnd();
for(int i=size;i>0;i--){
    id=node.getid();
    sepall=node.getsepall();
    sepalw=node.getsepalw();
    petall=node.getpetall();
    petalw=node.getpetalw();
    petal=petalw*petall;
    sepal=sepalw*sepall;
    double s1=sepal1-sepal;
    double s2=sepal2-sepal;
    double p1=petal1-petal;
    double p2=petal2-petal;
    s1=Math.abs(s1);
    s2=Math.abs(s2);
    p1=Math.abs(p1);
    p2=Math.abs(p2);

    if(s1<s2){  //if sepal is closer to 2
        if(p1<p2){

        }else{
            double s=s2-s1;
            double p=p1-p2;
            if(s>p){

            }else{
                listA.deleteAtPos(i);
                listB.insertAtEnd(id,sepall,sepalw,petall,petalw);
            }
        }
    }else{
        if(p2<p1){
            listA.deleteAtPos(i);
            listB.insertAtEnd(id,sepall,sepalw,petall,petalw);
        }else{
            double s=s1-s2;
            double p=p2-p1;
            if(s>p){
                listA.deleteAtPos(i);
                listB.insertAtEnd(id,sepall,sepalw,petall,petalw);
            }else{

            }
        }

    }
node=node.getPrev();
}
size=listB.getSize();
node=listB.getEnd();
for(int i=size;i>0;i--){
    id=node.getid();
    sepall=node.getsepall();
    sepalw=node.getsepalw();
    petall=node.getpetall();
    petalw=node.getpetalw();
    petal=petalw*petall;
    sepal=sepalw*sepall;
    double s1=sepal1-sepal;
    double s2=sepal2-sepal;
    double p1=petal1-petal;
    double p2=petal2-petal;
    s1=Math.abs(s1);
    s2=Math.abs(s2);
    p1=Math.abs(p1);
    p2=Math.abs(p2);

    if(s2<s1){  //if sepal is closer to 2
        if(p2<p1){

        }else{
            double s=s2-s1;
            double p=p1-p2;
            if(s>p){

            }else{
                listB.deleteAtPos(i);
                listA.insertAtEnd(id,sepall,sepalw,petall,petalw);
            }
        }
    }else{
        if(p2<p1){
            listB.deleteAtPos(i);
            listA.insertAtEnd(id,sepall,sepalw,petall,petalw);
        }else{
            double s=s2-s1;
            double p=p1-p2;
            if(s>p){
                listB.deleteAtPos(i);
                listA.insertAtEnd(id,sepall,sepalw,petall,petalw);
            }else{

            }
        }

    }
node=node.getPrev();
}
}
```

Comment: You  said "... I'm getting an error relating to the input ..."   This is like telling your doctor that you're getting a symptom.  What's the actual error?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "" and then goes into at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)

Comment: You should add a printout of each value so that you can see the value causing the Exception. The exception is likely telling you that what you are trying to parse as a number is not a number. The exception information you provided is not complete enough to know which line in your code this is occurring with.

Comment: Well, that error means that you are passing an empty string to one of your `Integer.parseInt` or `Double.parseDouble` calls.  It probably indicates that there's a line in your input file with some fields missing, or possibly even a blank line.